# What fields in Azure AD or Teams Provisioning are the source of entities.country/locale info in the JSON delivered to Teams App messaging endpoint?

Tags: azure-active-directory, botframework, microsoft-teams

Microsoft Teams <-> Azure AD Bot Registration w/ Teams Channel <-> Custom Teams App/Bot Messaging End Point using Bot Framework.

We have a Custom Teams App built using Microsoft Bot Framework. We wish to use some of geo attributes provided by Teams to the messaging end point  in the incoming messaging delivered from Teams to our chat bot, in particular entities.country and entities.locale   (These are described in Microsoft Schema https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-conversations/bots-conversations#full-inbound-schema-example  and excerpted below)

[image]

We believe that these attributes are sourced from Azure AD User Profile, but would like to know which field. And if not from Azure AD data which data fields or configurations.

We have a customer where the Country (CO and C) are properly set as a country other than US, however Teams Bot Conversation JSON  reports US as the country in entities.country and not the country configured in Azure AD.   (Teams tenant appears to be hosted in Western Europe, so somehow during the Teams license provisioning perhaps some country attributes are getting over ridden from their values in Azure AD).

Comment: The locale that comes to bot gets populated from Teams settings. We will confirm about the other fields and let you know

Answer (score 1):

entities.country and entities.locale get populated from the Teams settings. We tried as below.

1. When the APP language is English(US), we got the below payload at the bot endpoint.

[image]

```
"entities": [
        {
            "locale": "en-US",
            "country": "US",
            "platform": "Web",
            "timezone": "Asia/Calcutta",
            "type": "clientInfo"
        }
    ]
```

2. When the APP language is English(India), we got the below payload at the bot endpoint.

[image]

```
"entities": [
        {
            "locale": "en-IN",
            "country": "IN",
            "platform": "Web",
            "timezone": "Asia/Calcutta",
            "type": "clientInfo"
        }
    ]
```